# Jasmine: require is not defined

Tags: jasmine, angular

I did angular2 quick start project through this link: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart. The only different is I add code `var fs =  require('js')` in app.component.ts, it works. But when I write Jasmine unit test for that component, it shows `require is not defined`, does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Note:

I am using typescript in my whole project.

I have tried to add node typings definition, but it doesn't fix the bug.

Here is my code:
unit-tests.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Ng App Unit Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
<!-- Unit Testing Chapter #1: Proof of life.  -->
<script src="app/app.component.spec.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the code for your spec runner? - I'm assuming you're using a specrunner.html...

Comment: It's the same as unit-tests.html in the website, see the code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include SystemJS and import your spec.

Something like:

```
<script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>  
    System.config({
        baseURL: '/app'
    });
      System.import('app.component.spec')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post your component code? I will create a plunk for you

Comment: Here is my plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/zmmOQSZcRgpbIyifRKxx?p=preview  For some reason, it doesn't work. But in my app, I have the similar code, it works, it only doesn't work when doing testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a this keyword that typescript required for all class members.

Change your component to this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
      this.testReq();
  }

  testReq(str: string): string {
    /*  var fs = require('fs');
      var str = '123';
      return str;*/
  }
}
```

I think you have misunderstood a few things here. FS is a node library for dealing with the file system. This works brilliantly when you are in a Node process, but in your example you are not. You are running in a browser process, therefore you do not have access to any of the node libraries.

Comment: Of course, I have more code than the above one, for example, I used fs to read files inside function testReq (they actually works in my app, just don't work in Jasmine testing). In this example, I just simplified the code to let you know where I require fs.